# Java Script. Библиотеки для работы с HTTP запросами

Tags: javascript, http

Проблема такая, нужно в Java Script работать с HTTP запросами. То есть находить данные запроса, немного изменять и отправлять этот же запрос на дугой хост. Есть ли какие-то библиотеки, с помощью которых можно было бы работать со всеми методами?

Comment: а где должен работать это код?

Comment: реализую сервер, который будет фаззить параметры HTTP запроса

Comment: почему готовый не использовать?